# .htaccess RewriteRule to include post type and taxonomy

Tags: url-rewriting, htaccess

I'm trying to rewrite this url www.domain.com/gallery/?university=birmingham to an seo friendly one like this www.domain.com/uni/birmingham/gallery

the (?university=birmingham) represent the taxonomy
and gallery is the post type.  At the moment this url (www.domain.com/gallery/?university=birmingham) works fine, it displays the right posts, just haven't had any success in rewriting it to the one above

I have tried doing this (which should work):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^uni/([0-9A-Za-z_-]+)/(.+)$ /$2?university=$1 [QSA,NC,L,R=302]


# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /students/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /students/index.php [L]


</IfModule>
```

can anyone please point me in the right direction or show me what am doing wrong?

Comment: Why aren't you using the [WordPress rewrite API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API)?

Comment: I couldn't figure out, how to do it in that, so I just figured it would be easier to do it in the htaccess file.

Comment: Trust me, it might be easier *right now*, but you'll soon have a bigger headache than if you start reading up on the rewrite API.

Answer (score 0):

This rewrite rule will surely work. Add this code to your .htaccess file.
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^uni/([^/]*)$ /gallery/?university=$1 [L]

Comment: I tried your solution didn't work